# How can i run a particular feature file across different browsers simultaneously with Behat?

Tags: php, behat, mink

Basically what i want to achieve/know is, is it possible to run my scenarios across different browsers simultaneously ?? 
I know it is possible to run test on different browsers by configuring the profiles in behat.yml
However what if i want want to run all the profile parallel ??

Comment: Open multiple shells and run each browser configuration individually. Or automate by using a small script that sends each behat command into the background, effectively doing the same.

Comment: @PedroLobito currently im running my scripts using different profiles in yml for different browers. However they run one after the other for each browser

Answer (score 0):

Use a payed cloud service (browserstack, saucelabs or others) or start multiple selenium servers on different ports with different drivers and add specific wd_host for each profile.